# How to define errors inside a sqlloader ctl file

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

with the aim of importing data automatically into an Oracle database, I created a CTL file using the SQL*Loader. I would like to add some clause to this file that allows me to block the file upload and to stop it when it finds an error. How can I do? What should I put inside the CTL file?

Comment: Well, yes - you can do that, but **why** stop at first error? Wouldn't you rather let it load everything it can, so that you'd then review all errors in log, discard and bad file so that you could fix as many errors as you can, and then reload data? If you stop at the first error, you have no idea what to expect next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `errors=0` to the `sqlldr` command line arguments, which is the way it's normally done. Or you can also place this line inside the control file just before "`LOAD DATA`":

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=0)
```